# Time Value Formula, IF statement check box

Tags: formula, formula-field, time

I've been trying to work out some sort of syntax for a simple custom checkbox to be ticked when it's time based.
So far i've created this:

```
IF( TIMEVALUE(" > 16:00:00.125  < 16:05:00.125"), true, false)
```

Although I am stuck on where to go from here...

Basically I wanted it this to tick itself within a time frame everyday.
So between 16:00 and 16:05 everyday, this box is ticked - any other time of day it is not ticked.
Honestly no idea if this is possible, although I would imagine with boxes ticking themselves after an amount of X days etc.

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: As written, this is an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Formula values only evaluate when they are read from the database. They don't physically exist and do not update records in the database. What is the business logic you're trying to implement?

Comment: basically a pause feature to stop a triggered flow running after a scheduled flow. A bit more background: I've created a scheduled flow that runs everyday. Now this is to put the last login date of that user record into a custom field. However when the flow ends, the triggered flow notices the updated record and puts in the current last modified date into this custom field (which it's kinda supposed to do, but only on a human edit level). I want the check box to tick itself at the time the scheduled flow runs, so after it's ran the conditions of the trigger flow is not made and doesn't re-edit

Comment: Hopefully that makes sense..

Comment: Perfect sense. I have an idea.

Comment: A bit more of a background, if it helps.. this is for a GDPR project. All other objects case, leads etc. However the link between a user and contact record is a real stump. Mainly the partner users. Very happy to share my entire project on here for others.. its just this one final piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

[Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.customize_functions_parent.htm&type=5) is a good reference, and that should probably be everyone's first stop when they run into errors (or are just looking for things that might help them accomplish something).

In this case, using `TIMEVALUE()` like this is not correct. You need to either pass it a datetime field, or a time string (formatted like `"hh:mm:ss.ms"`). It cannot do time comparisons.

Even if it could, comparisons are *always binary* (that is, they take 2 parameters), so things of the form `1 < x < 2` are *basically never valid* (in my example because the `1 < x` bit is evaluated first and returns a boolean, and `true/false < 2` makes no sense). When you have multiple comparisons to make, you need to explicitly make all of them (e.g. `AND(1 < x, x < 2)` in my contrived example).

You'd also have to take timezones into consideration. Would you want this to be true when it is 16:00-16:05 in *your* timezone, *even if a person is viewing this outside of your timezone*? Or do you want it to be true from 16:00 - 16:05 in the user's own timezone?

Further, `IF(<condition>, true, false)` can *always* be simplified to just `<condition>`. The logical test in an `IF()` already returns a boolean (true/false) value. The inverse, `IF(<condition>, false, true)` simplifies to `NOT(<condition>)`.

With all that said, an assuming that you want this in one specific timezone (e.g. the org's default time zone), you'd do something like this

```java
/* AND() returns true only if all of the things inside of it are true */
AND(
    /* Assuming you're UTC +1 */
    /* TIMENOW() gets you the GMT (i.e. UTC) time */
    /* + 1/24 adds one hour to that */
    TIMENOW() + 1/24 >= TIMEVALUE("16:00:00.000"),
    TIMENOW() + 1/24 <= TIMEVALUE("16:05:00.000")
)
```

At least I think that's how you'd handle mixing UTC and local time (it's either addition or subtraction).

One other important thing to note is that formulas don't store the result of the formula. It gets recalculated every time that a record is accessed, and formulas cannot cause automation (triggers, flows, etc...) to fire.

Comment: Thank you, I see what you mean. My statement shouldn't be an IF statement, but a condition that if met = true. I am not worried about timezones here, so you're right ti assume there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd design this. The Record Triggered Flow should be a Before Save Flow. If the custom field is empty, copy the Last Login Date value to the field, and quit. Otherwise, assume it is a user edit and copy the last modified date. Now, the Scheduled Flow simply clears out the custom field and calls Update Records. Alternatively, with a Before Save Flow, add a second field that the Scheduled Flow will tick, and the Before Save Flow can determine which action to take based on if the second custom field is true or not, then reset the flag.

Comment: Thank you! Interesting, I was trying to figure something like this out, but didn't know the correct way to do it. I'll give this a try and report back to both of you!

Answer (score 0):

Update -
So the formular option didnt work as I intended (Derek did mention this) - However I did try their solution with it and I failed.
However sfdcfox's solution did work - In another sense that was quite hard to get my head around.

The solution works as intended and offer another condition for the triggered flow to basically ignore any updated record that the scheduled flow completes.

I don't know if there is any interest in this, however as I said - I'm going to share my flows to help anyone who may need them (perhaps I should create another post for this?)
Here is the flows:

1. The scheduled flow that is ran daily
   [image: Scheduled flow]

Conditions for flow: Custom field added to check if the record is to be deleted, to avoid API users, etc.
[image: Conditions]
The Null decision element, pretty self explanatory, so I wont post a snap of that.
The other decision element:
[image: Option1]
[image: Option2]
This is the update element:
[image: Update element]
You can see the new field called pause block for this is the flag that gets ticked now when it has ran.

Variable created to get rid of time from time and date field of last login date, enables the equals condition to run correctly.
[image: Varible]

Now the triggered flow:
[image: Triggerflow]
Same conditions basically, is deleteable and is active checked. Record when created or updated.
optimized for fast field updates too.
Same Null element as the first flow, going to decision element's first option
[image: d1]
Next one:
unable to add pictures now..
both LLID and last mod same: - LLIDWithoutTime - equals - record>gdprdate
AND record>GDPR - equals - True
AND Record>pauseblock - equals - True
And the final decision:
Block Ticked? : Record>Pauseblock - equals - True
AND Record>GDPR - equals - True.

update if last login better:
update element: field: GDPR Date user c <- Value: Record>LastLogin
Update if last mod is better:
update element: field: GDPR Date user c <- Value: Today (formula date, TODAY())

Removal of pause block to end:
update element: condition pauseblock equals true.
set field: Field Pauseblock c <- False

Thank you both for your help Derek and sfdcFox